# If $f$ is bounded and continuous and $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} X$, do we have $f(X_n) \xrightarrow{a.s.} f(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Basically the title, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous and the sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$ converges to $X$ in probability, do we have almost sure convergence of $f(X_1), f(X_2), ...$ to $f(X)$?

Comment: What you are saying is basically that the convergence in proba implies the almost sure convergence, which is not true.

Comment: No, but you will have $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as a counterexample take $f(x) = x$.  Then you're asking whether convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence, which it doesn't.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is not bounded

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that condition. I will revise

Comment: Actually the same basic idea still works. Let $f$ be any bounded continuous function such that $f(x)=x$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Then let $X1, X2, \dots$ be a sequence of RVs taking values in $[0,1]$ that converge to $0$ in probability but not almost surely (for example the typewriter sequence)

Comment: Fair enough, thanks